# Conversion of 3D WireFrame into 3D Solid Models

Tags: c, 3d, autocad, cad

I have been working with some 3D Wire Frame Models, which are essentially a large number of vertices which are joined together by edges or line segments to create a 3D Wire Frame of a 3D Object.

I was wondering what would it take to convert this `3D Wire Frame Model` into a `3D Solid Model`. What algorithms can be used to achieve this?

Right now what I have is a sequence of points that I join together using line segments,What would it take me to fill the regions created by these line segments to produce a 3d Solid Model?

The platform is Linux using C.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is breaking the wireframe model into separate triangles. Than you can assign surface parameters to the triangles, such as color information.